# Add a link to the title of references

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, bibliography, csl

I'm creating a document with rmarkdown (pandoc), which includes some bibliography in a `.bib` file. What I'd like to do is add a link to the title of the references, so that each of them links to a page of the form `http://sample.com/citation-key.html`, like this:

> Author. (2017). [Sample Title](http://sample.com/author2017word.html). Journal, 1(1), 1–2.

I've tried modifying the `.csl` file by adding prefixes and suffixes to the title, but everything I put in there is escaped, whether I use markdown or HTML syntax. Unfortunately, I can't change the `.bib` file. The relevant part of the `.csl` file is this:

```
<text variable="title"/>
```

Sample files are:

- `literature.Rmd`:

  ```md
  ---
  output: html_document
  bibliography: literature.bib
  csl: literature.csl
  ---

  @author2017word says this doesn't work.

  ## References
  ```
- `literature.bib`

  ```tex
  @article{author2017word,
           author = {Author},
           journal = {Journal},
           number = {1},
           pages = {1--2},
           title = {{Sample Title}},
           volume = {1},
           year = {2017}
  }
  ```
- `literature.csl`: I'm using the APA style [from here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/citation-style-language/styles/master/apa.csl) (line 231).

Comment: Can you go into details about the link adress? Would it be http://sample.com/author2017word.html in this example?

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer yep, exactly, though the problem is not so much the actual url as it is to add any url.

Comment: And the final document is HTML? You could add the links afterwards with jQuery. Would that be sufficient?

Comment: Yep, it'll be HTML. Postprocessing with JS would be the last resort. Ideally it'll have to be hardcoded in the HTML.

Comment: Just to say that you definitely *can't* do this with CSL. I think it's also not available in pandoc, so Martin's suggestion to postprocess is the only way to go, but not certain about the latter one.

Comment: Well, at this point a JS-based solution would be fine then. Anyone up for it?

Comment: Came here wanting to do the same. I've been manuallly adding urls via `<a href="...">...</a>` to each of the `title` fields in my `.bib` file, but wanted to see if I could get CSL to do this for me.  @adam.smith's answer makes me sad but also spares me a lot of headache trying in vain to customize my CSL file.

Answer (score 3):

My [pull request](https://github.com/jgm/citeproc/pull/88) to `citeproc` adding support this feature was recently merged, and as a result, **the latest release of Pandoc (v2.14.2) now hyperlinks titles *by default*** when the citation does not already show a raw URL!  From the `citeproc` readme:

> When `linkBibliography=True` automatically linkifies any identifiers (DOI, PMCID, PMID, or URL) appearing in a bibliography entry. When an entry has a DOI, PMCID, PMID, or URL available but none of these are rendered by the style, add a link to the title (or, if no title is present, the whole entry), using the URL for the DOI, PMCID, PMID, or URL (in that order of priority). See [Appendix VI](https://github.com/citation-style-language/documentation/blob/master/specification.rst#appendix-vi-links) of the CSL v1.0.2 spec.

In pandoc, this option is controlled by the [`link-bibliography` metadata field](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#other-relevant-metadata-fields), which is `True` by default.